# Different publishers of kovetz mefarshim

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, jewish-books

I'm wondering what the different major publishers of kovetz mefarshim on Gemara are, and if there are any pros/cons to the different editions. In general, and if known regarding Kiddushin specifically.

Comment: In addition to the standard [*Y'rid HaSfarim*](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=9553) and [*K'lilas Yofi/Tif'eres HaTorah*](https://www.judaicaplace.com/kovetz-meforshim-kiddushin-volume-1-kelilas-yofi-hardcover/z1103/) editions that have been around for a long time, there is also the [*Kovetz M'farshim HaKollel*](https://judaicaplaza.com/products/75881481) from מכון כנסת. Oz Vehadar also puts out their own edition on some tractates, but not on Kiddushin.

Comment: The most widely used is the K'lilas Yofi edition. But the real answer is whatever you like better. Go to a store and compare the different ones in person.